# Calculating Voltage

Tags: voltage, analysis

I am trying to calculate the voltage \$Vw\$ of the following circuit:

[image: example schematic]

I have little experience with these kind of problems, so I tried to solve first a more simple circuit that did not include the R2-L2-C2-R4 branch.

In the simplified circuit, I considered it as a voltage divider with \$\frac{1}{Z1} = \frac{1}{R1+sL1} + \frac{1}{R3}\$ and \$Z2 = R5+sL5+\frac{1}{sC5}\$. Then, I solved \$V_w = V_{\text{in}}\frac{Z2}{Z1+Z2}\$, transformed back to the time domain. I compared with a circuit implemented in SPICE with the same results.

Now, the problem is that I don't know if I can continue to use the voltage divider strategy because C2 is connected to ground.

What tips, strategy (or elements that I am probably not considering) would you suggest to calculate this \$V_w\$ ? How does SPICE solve this problem?

(I would like to clarify that I do not have an electrical or electronic background or studies. Therefore, I usually have some knowledge *gaps*).

---

Edit:

Here is the SPICE circuit that I am using in order to compare my results, with a simple unit step for \$V_{\text{in}}\$.

```
* example

Vin    1 0 DC 1

R1  1 4       2
L1  4 Vw      2 IC=0

R3  1 Vw      5

R2  1 2       1
L2  2 3       1 IC=0
C2  3 0       1 IC=0 
R4  3 Vw      5

R5   Vw 5      1
L5   5  6      1 IC=0
C5   6  0      1 IC=0

.control
tran .0001s 2s 0s .0001s uic
.endc

.end
```

Comment: Voltage at Vw with respect to *what*?  Also is anything connected to the dangling ends of C2 and C5?  If not, you can just ignore them and delete them from the schematic.  Actually, with C2 gone, R1, L1, R2, L2, and R4 all do nothing too.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to specify that. Vin is with respect to ground. I need Vw with respect to ground as well. And finally, both capacitors are connected to ground too.

Comment: If you remove the bottom branch of the circuit, where do R1 and L1 connect?  I don't know how you can get the same result as SPICE because your equations don't describe the circuit you would get if you removed those components.

Comment: @Bitrex: I added the SPICE circuit in order to clear that...

Comment: @Yuppie: If those capacitors are supposed to be connected to ground, then please fix the schematic to show that.

Comment: @Yuppie - Is the R1/R2 junction intended to be connected to Vin? It looks that way according to your SPICE netlist. If so it's missing a "dot". As suggested, fixing the schematic will help prevent confusion.

Comment: I have fixed the schematic as suggested. I am guessing that a dot is needed as well at C2. So I've just added that as well

Comment: Vital questions: WHY do you want this?, what is it for?, why do you think the circuit is correct?, is the mow modified circuit correct? , do you have component values? || Is this an assignment. That's not bad - just may change how we look at the question (where are the "traps" etc.

Comment: @Russell: The circuit is for solving models of (zero-dimension) pressures and flows of a tube system using an electric analogy. RLC circuits represent tubes with wall friction, fluid inertia and elasticity of tube walls. RL circuits are analogous but without elasticity. R are tubes with no fluid inertia or elastic walls. The structure of the circuit reflects a certain tube configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(this is in regards to the fixed schematic)

I think your general approach is correct, but the addition of the branch with C2 complicates things.  I think this would be a good opportunity to apply the "Extra Element Theorem."  Call C2 the extra element, and remove it from the circuit. The EET then states that the transfer function of the circuit is going to be \$H_\infty \frac{1 + \frac{Z_n}{Z}}{1 + \frac{Zd}{Z}}\$, where Zn is the impedance looking in to the node where C2 is connected when Vin is set to be an infinite impedance, and Vw is nulled to zero volts.  \$Z_d\$ is the impedance looking in to the node where C2 is connected when Vin is set to zero, and the node Vw left alone.  \$H_\infty\$ is the input to output transfer function when C2 is out of the circuit, that is the same voltage division type transfer function you calculated earlier but with R2, L2, and R4 added to the parallel combination.

It will probably still be a messy expression, but I think it will be easier to calculate than using nodal analysis.

Edit: Z in the equation above is the impedance of the extra element.

Answer (score 2):

So I was bored:
[image]
<sup>The image is a link to the simulation</sup>

---

The Falstad Circuit simulator is nice, but it's probably not quite as accurate as SPICE.
It's nice for testing and getting a feel of how different component values affect the circuit, though.

Answer (score 1):

SPICE converts everything into matrix format, using techniques that don't seem trivial.

I find that redrawing the circuit is usually my first strategy:

[image]

You'll need to find the impedance of the L1-R1-R2-L2 branch, put it in parallel with R4, then in series with C2, then in parallel with the R5-L5-C5 branch. Once you get that impedance, your divider is trivial. : )

Comment: I am under the impression that my diagram is not at all clear because I don't see how yours is equivalent to mine... :S I posted a SPICE code that may explain it better

Comment: @Yuppie: Spice code is no substitute for a proper schematic.  Fix the schematic.

Comment: @Yuppie - Madmanguruman has taken your schematic as drawn, with Vin connected only to R3. See my other comment about the junction, if one is intended at Vin/R1/R2/R3 then you need to alter it.

Comment: Oy. What a mess.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is to draw the schematic in a more comprehensible form and use proper symbols:

[image]

From this it is immediately obvious that R1 and R2 are in series, as are L1 and L2.  A simplified equivalent schematic is therefore:

[image]

Where L6 = L1 + L2 and R6 = R1 + R2.

That's a little simpler but not simple enough to just solve by looking at it.  The way to proceed is by writing the complex impedance of each element, then doing the appropriate series and parallel combinations for everything except R3.  At that point you have a voltage divider with R3 on top and the equivalent complex impedance of the rest on the bottom.  Solve as a voltage divider using complex impedances.  Yuk.  It can be done though.  This reminds me homework problems from long ago.

### Added:

Argh!  I see you have now altered the schematic to something quite different after I spent the time to nicely draw and simplify what you had.  You really need to be more careful before posting questions.  I'm now a lot less inclined to spend time on your questions in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Ok after seeing this question I had to give it a go ... it was to interesting not to try.

The first thing I noticed is the numbering and thought that might be a hint, but I could not get R2, L2 and c2 as Z2 ... I had to change C2 to C6 to enable coming up with a diagram and equations to solve for Vw.

First up convert the discretes into impedances as follows:

```
Z1 = 1/(1/(L1s + R1) + 1/R3)
Z2 = L2s + R2
Z4 = R4
Z5 = L5s + R5 + 1/C5s
Z6 = 1/C6s
```

from here I redrew the circuit as

```
Vin -------------
     |         | 
    Z2        Z1
     |         |
V2   +--Z4-----+     Vw
     |         |
     Z6       Z5
     |         |
     -----------      ground
```

From here I used KCL to develop the following nodal equations:

```
Iin = I1 + I2  eq 1
I2 =  I4 + I6  eq 2
I5 =  I4 + I1  eq 3
```

Where the currents are the currents in each element going top to bottom and Z4 is going left to right.

next step rearrange eq3 and sub in eq3 and eq2 into eq1

```
I1 = I5 - I4
Iin = I5 - I4 + I4 + I6
Iin = I5 + I6 eq4
```

change the currents to voltages which yeilds the following

```
Iin = (Vin - Vw)/Z1 + (Vin - V2)/Z2
I5 = Vw/Z5
I6 = V2/Z6
```

finally subing back into eq4 gives:

```
(Vin - Vw)/Z1 + (Vin - V2)/Z2 = Vw/Z5 + V2/Z6
```

then solve for Vw!! hope this helps :)

Comment: What happened to Z3 ?

Comment: I think you mean (Vin - Vout)/Z1 instead of (Vout - Vout)/Z1 in the above equations.

Comment: Z3 has been moved to form part of Z1 as it is in parrallel

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to make a DC Transient analysis? If the input is DC, the inductors become shorts and the caps become open. This means that Vw is floating (no reference from Vin to another potential source, such as ground).

This actually makes the circuit very simple to analyze, assuming you have a ground somewhere, because all you have to worry about are the resistors.

**EDIT** 
I realize in my previously posted diagram I was missing a junction you had in your question. However, the above answer remains valid.

Comment: In the SPICE example I use a DC input. This is an initial test only. Afterwards my input will be AC

Comment: If it's high-frequency AC, you can still make this approximation. But if you test with DC in spice, your answer will be completely different with a lower frequency AC (ie any function input that's not constant).